# How to simply Update Labels with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a current student working on programming problem. I was wondering if I could help with a Tkinter and Labelling Items.

I am currently using labels for my program since they look the best, and are far easier to format when compared to text or other such things. Anyway...

The current problem I have is that my label won't update, I am currently using this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

#Window Initilisation
root = Tk()
root.title('CafeAuLait Ordering')

#Product Prices
Cappu_CSt = (3.75) #Cappucino cost

#Defining Variables
TotaldCost = (0)
Reciptext = ('Developer Version')

Display = Label(root, width=35, bg='white', height=10, text=str(Reciptext))
Display.grid(row=1,column=3, columnspan=4, rowspan=8)
 
def button_cappucino():
    global TotaldCost
    global Reciptext
    global Cappu_CSt
    TotaldCost = TotaldCost + Cappu_CSt
    Display = ((str(Reciptext) + '''
    Cappucino ----- $'''+ str(Cappu_CSt)))
    print('Test')

cappucino = Button(root, text='1x Cappucino',width=10 ,borderwidth=5, command=button_cappucino)
price_LabelCCP = Label(root, text='---$3.75', bg='#FFF6AD')

cappucino.grid(row=1, column=1)
price_LabelCCP.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I get the test back in terminal, which indicates that the button is indeed running, but despite this the Label does not update, staying with just the text 'Developer Version' Does anyone know a simple way I can update the label? Many thanks.

Comment: You can not update lable's text like this. Lable is an object and you are assigning it a value like its string variable.
To update lable in tkinter, [try this method](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-change-the-tkinter-label-text/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign text directly to a widget. You have to assign text to the proper widget property. You have other issues, though. I fixed your logic and explained it in comments.

```
#don't pollute your namespace with *
import tkinter as tk

#Window Initilisation
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Cafe-Au-Lait Ordering')

#your variables had strange names and value syntax
pricelist = []
purchases = []
header    = 'Developer Version\n'
offset    = 0    #first line items will be printed on ~ set internally
selected  = -1   #used as a purchase index ~ -1 means nothing is selected


#by listing the properties of your items this way
#~you can create and manage buttons dynamically
items =[
    {'name':'Cappucino',    'cost':3.89},
    {'name':'Mochasippi',   'cost':3.59},
    {'name':'Black Coffee', 'cost':2.19},
    {'name':'Water',        'cost':1.59},
    {'name':'Orange Juice', 'cost':1.89},
    {'name':'Milk',         'cost':1.89},
    {'name':'Croissant',    'cost':2.59},
    {'name':'Danish',       'cost':2.59},
]


#force an extra dummy row to take up all remaining space
root.grid_rowconfigure(len(items), weight=1)
#force Text display to resize with window
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

#only Text widgets are truly multiline
receipt_txt = tk.Text(root, width=35, bg='white', cursor='arrow', height=20)
receipt_txt.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=len(items)+1, sticky='nswe') #span to include dummy row

#init receipt
receipt_txt.insert('1.0', header) 
receipt_txt.insert('4.0', '\ntotal: $0.00') 
receipt_txt.tag_configure('selected', background='#FFF6AD')
receipt_txt.config(state='disabled')       #disable receipt


#select a line for complete item deletion
def select(event):
    global selected
    global offset
    
    #line number that was clicked
    b = int(receipt_txt.index('@%d,%d' % (event.x, event.y)).split('.')[0])
    #the "total: $00.00" line number
    e = int(receipt_txt.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])
    #the text
    t = receipt_txt.get(f'{b}.0', f'{b}.end').strip()
    #if the line falls within the item range and has text
    if b in range(offset, e) and t:
        #reposition selected tag
        receipt_txt.tag_remove("selected", '1.0', 'end')
        receipt_txt.tag_add("selected", f'{b}.0', f'{b}.end')
    
    #used as 'purchases' index    
    selected = b - offset


#rewrite receipt and reconsider pricelist, selected and offset
def retotal():
    global pricelist
    global purchases
    global selected
    global offset
    global header
    
    selected  = -1                          #unset selected
    pricelist = []                          #reset pricelist
    
    receipt_txt.config(state='normal')      #enable receipt for writing
    receipt_txt.delete('1.0', 'end')        #remove all text
    receipt_txt.insert('1.0', header)       #rewrite header
    
    #store the line that items will start on
    offset   = int(receipt_txt.index('end-1c').split('.')[0]) + 1 #because item starts with \n
    
    #rewrite all items
    for it in purchases:
        if it:
            pricelist.append(it["cost"])                 #rewrite pricelist
            strcost = f'${format(it["cost"], ".2f")}'    #create string of cost
            #write item to receipt
            receipt_txt.insert('end-1c', f'\n{it["name"]:<16} ---- {strcost:>{16-len(strcost)}}')
                                          
    #rewrite "total" line
    receipt_txt.insert('end-1c', f'\n\ntotal: ${format(sum(pricelist), ".2f")}') 
    receipt_txt.config(state='disabled')    #disable receipt


#handles all item purchases
def add_item(item):
    global purchases
    
    purchases.append(item) #append to purchases
    retotal()              #reconsider receipt


#handles all item removals    
def remove_item(event=None, purchase_num=None):
    global purchases
    global selected
    
    selected = selected if not purchase_num else purchase_num
    
    if selected in range(0, len(purchases)):
        purchases.pop(selected) #append to purchases
        retotal()              #reconsider receipt


#unset selected    
def unselect(event=None):
    global selected
    selected = -1    


#receipt is left-clicked
receipt_txt.bind('<1>', select)
#receipt loses focus ~ unset 'selected'
receipt_txt.bind('<FocusOut>', unselect)
#delete key was pressed ~ remove purchase and retotal
receipt_txt.bind('<Delete>', remove_item)

#create all register buttons dynamically
for i, v in enumerate(items):
    tk.Button(root, text=v['name'], width=15, command=lambda v=v: add_item(v)).grid(row=i, column=0, sticky='nw', pady=0)
    tk.Label(root, text=f"${format(v['cost'], '.2f')}", bg='#FFF6AD').grid(row=i, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but line 121 throws an error when I use the Visual Studio IDE, do you know why this would be?

Comment: @Schmilly ~ I made an edit and changed how that line reads. Try it now.

Comment: @Schmilly ~ If my answer helped you would you consider accepting it (click the checkmark to the left of the answer). Thanks.